# Xamarin.iOS new default project template app shows error: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I set up a new default project template Xamarin.iOS App in Visual Studio 2017 and want to test the app on my Mac mini build host when the app displays the following debug info:

> iOSTestApp[...] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
>
> iOSTestApp[...] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: iOSTestApp

After reading [this question:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237465/what-means-sectaskloadentlitlements-failed-error-22) I thought it was related to the signing of the `Entitlements`. I don't use any Entitlements in the new app so that shouldn't be the problem.

Did anyone come across the same problem and knows how to deal with it?

My development setup is:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.9.2

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0

Xamarin   4.12.3.72

Xamarin Designer   4.16.11

Xamarin Templates   1.1.127

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.2.1.10
```

Edit: Updated VS 15.9.2 -> 15.9.5 but no changes

Comment: If two project use different `Entitlements`, the same provisioning / bundle signing setup may not sure that also work.In addition, can first update VS to newest version,then rebuild project and check whether be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I am using the default Entitlements.plist without any modifications. I will update VS to 15.9.5 and try to redeploy as soon as i get my hands on the build host again.

Comment: Can you work on any ios project properly? My best guess is that your wi-fi has some problems in connection

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Other (older) iOS projects run fine. Moreover, i am having the same problem when i run an iPhone application from XCode locally on the Mac.

Comment: Same problem in 2021, latest Visual Studio on Mac, freshly reinstalled, any ideas? @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: @adamsfamily Whether you are using the **Visual Studio 2019** create the project and copy to vs for mac to check?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, same problem on VS for Mac, latest update (v8.8.9 build 10).

Comment: @adamsfamily Hi, not VS 2017, whether you have used VS 2019 to check?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi, yes, I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 fo Mac, Version 8.8.10 (build 2).

Comment: @adamsfamily Okey, it's strange. You could submit it as an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose) in Github.

Comment: see my answer. this error drove me nuts for like 6 hours of googling. I walked back all my recent changes one by one and finally figured it out. Not a very helpful error message.. oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this error came up too. It was caused by an infinite recursive loop. I had a property that called itself by accident due to a typo:

```
string name;

public string Name {
    get => Name; // this capitalization error caused it. Should be name.
}
```

Check any recently written code for an infinite loop perhaps!